# Probability after choices are already made

Tags: probability

It's been a while since my statistics course and I was wondering if someone could help me with the following question:

All trainers work in the accounting department.
60% of the trainers are bilingual.
Joe is a trainer.

What can be validly concluded from the information provided above?

1. Joe is 60% likely to be bilingual
2. Joe is 40% likely to be not bilingual
3. We can't determine whether Joe is bilingual or not
4. Joe is bilingual

I believe that option 3 is the best answer because Joe either is or is not bilingual. I think that the answer would be different if the question asked about a "random employee".

Answer (score 1):

I would write down what you know and what you're looking for.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{accounting}|\text{trainer}) &=& 1 \\
P(\text{bilingual}|\text{trainer}) &=& 0.6 \\
\end{eqnarray*}$

We want to know $P(\text{Joe is bilingual})$.

I would make the step that, since Joe is a trainer, $P(\text{Joe is bilingual})=P(\text{bilingual}|\text{Joe})=P(\text{bilingual}|\text{trainer})$.

Based on this, I think that 1, 2, and 3 are all valid conclusions.

Comment: Is it really true that $P(\textrm{bilingual | Joe}) = P(\textrm{bilingual | trainer})$? I think what the OP was getting at is this: does it make a difference that a specific employee, Joe, is chosen, rather than a random employee? Joe is either bilingual or not, so can we say that $P(\textrm{bilingual | Joe}) \in \{0,1\}$, whereas $P(\textrm{bilingual | trainer}) = 0.6$?

Comment: Ah, that's a really good point. It would follow the same logic as a confidence interval's probability of containing the parameter must be 0 or 1. Damn these subtle differences! :)

Comment: @Théophile I think you just highlighted the difference between a frequentist and a Bayesian interpretation. Personally, I think the Bayesian interpretation is more sensible here. I.e. what odds are you willing to take to bet money on Joe being bilingual? With which odds are you going to break even in the long run if you keep taking these bets?

Comment: @rinspy That makes sense, but I still have a problem with the wording of the question; I would want to know how Joe was chosen. We don't know what it means to look at the "long run" when we don't know what happened: was a random trainer chosen, and it happened to be Joe, or is Joe always chosen as the representative because he's so friendly?

Comment: @rinspy To put it another way, I see the question like this: "40% of the numbers from 1 to 10 are prime numbers. 8 is a number from 1 to 10. What is the probability that 8 is prime?"

Comment: @Théophile I agree, the wording makes the question ambiguous. But even in your example, if I do not know anything else about the number 8 apart from what is included in your question, my Bayesian probability (i.e., degree of belief) of 8 being a prime would be 40%. Ok - technically, my subjective probability could be anything, but I would argue that in the absence of any other information, assigning any other probability to 8 being a prime than 40% would be irrational.

Comment: @rinspy I guess we've found the difference between mathematicians and statisticians... ;)